# Is there a way of solving this typeError: connection.connect is not a function in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to connect my school project to a mysql database but I always get the error "TypeError: connection.connect is not a function". I am not quite sure how to fix it. I hope someone is able to solve this.

**My index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var connection = require('./database');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/form', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html' );
    console.log(req.url);
    console.log(req.path);
})

app.listen(4000, () =>{
    console.log("Server listening on port 4000");
    connection.connect((err) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected");
    })
});
```

**my database.js**

````
let mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports = () => {
    return mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'minigames',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root'
})}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connection` is the value exported from the database module.

The value you assigned to `module.exports` there is a function that you defined.

It is a plain, ordinary function and you have no assigned a `connect` property to it.

I'm guessing that `connect` is a property on the return value of `mysql.createConnection`, but if you want to access that object then, you need to **call** the function you defined in order to get that object.

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var connection = require('./database');


app.listen(4000, () =>{
    console.log("Server listening on port 4000");
    connection().connect((err) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected");
    })
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).